# linux vm login Using Shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

we have cloud virtual machines where we able to login using pem and ppk file through WinSCP & Putty. I am going to write a shell script program to login into these machines.I tried something like but did not work.

```
ssh -i ~/ec2.pem ubuntu@12.34.56.78

Permissions 0664 for '/home/cloud-user/house_keeping/conf/ecp.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /home/cloud-user/house_keeping/conf/ecp.pem`enter code here`
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: what error you got

Comment: Why do you have the `python` tag if this is a shell script problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
Permissions 0664 for '/home/cloud-user/house_keeping/conf/ecp.pem' are too open.
```

The manual page for `ssh` explans the permissions that should be on the private keys:

> These files contain sensitive data and should be readable by the user but not accessible by others (read/write/execute).

So you should change the permission to 0600 using

```
chmod 600 ~/ec2.pem
```